# Let bash loop over unknown number of variables

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file where a bunch of variables are defined. It could be one, four or twenty. They have names such as `ipt_rss` and `bhd_rss`. Let's call these variables `var_i`

Now, I'd like to let bash loop over these variables like this:

```
for all i in var_i do
    command1 arg command2 arg $var_1 > /some/directory/$var_i.rss
        echo "Success finding $var_i"
done
```

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the variables all *begin* with a common prefix, you can iterate over all such variable names and use indirect variable expansion on the results:

```
for var in ${!rss_*}; do  # rss_ipt, rss_bhd, etc
    command1 arg command2 arg "${!var}" > "/some/directory/${!var}.rss"
done
```

Otherwise, the best you can do is explicitly define an array of variable names, or hard-code the list of names:

```
vars=( ipt_rss bhd_rss ... )
for var in "${vars[@]}"; do
```

or

```
for var in ipt_rss bhd_rss; do
```